# Executing powershell from powercli for windows configuration

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, vsphere, powercli

I am trying to automate the VM creation steps by creating a powershell script. I was able to deploy the VM of a desired configuration using powercli on vSphere. After windows OS is intalled , I am trying to configure the the windows OS inside the VM that the script has created. One of the steps that I am trying to do is to enable Admin account in the windows. How do I connect these together ? I know I can run invoke-vmscript to run commands in VM but how do i run an admin privilege level command in powercli ?

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APPLD.png) When I try to do Enter-PSSession i get an error (check the link). The credentials I use to login are correct and I am able to login to the VM manually using those.

Answer (score 0):

(Don't have the rep to ask questions, so I'll make assumptions)

You can use PowerShell-Remoting to execute commands on the running system or you could use DSC (Desired State Configuration) with powershell to configure the new system.  What OS is it running?

Comment: Different versions of windows os

Answer (score 0):

In this case, VMName is the wrong parameter. You'll want to use ComputerName instead.

VMName and VMId usage is a Hyper-V feature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/powershell-direct